# GlassFish V3 is not creating ConnectionPool and JDBC resources for Postgresql while deploying the application

Tags: glassfish-3

When i deploy my EE application, jdbc resources are not being created. when i deploy my application in glassfish v2.x resources were created and application was deployed properly.
I copied the postgresql jar file in galssfish --> ext folder and i have changed the provider to Eclipse in Pesistence.xml

```
<provider> org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider </provider>
```

When i deploy the application, I am getting exception like:

```
SEVERE: Invalid resource : jdbc/demo7-datasource__pm
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Invalid resource : jdbc/demo7-datasource__pm
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/demo7-datasource__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:468)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/demo7-datasource__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.validateResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.setResourceInfo(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:537)
    ... 48 more

SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : jdbc/demo7-datasource__pm
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/demo7-datasource__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:468)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/demo7-datasource__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.validateResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl$MyDataSource.setResourceInfo(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:253)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:243)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:537)
    ... 48 more
```

what sort of the things need to do for creating jdbc resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the resource config either by setting up a connection pool and associated jdbc resource in the admin gui or with a glassfish-resources.xml.

See https://blogs.oracle.com/JagadishPrasath/entry/application_scoped_resources_in_glassfish

Comment: I have defined the connectionpool and jndi name in sun-resources.xml. but ear file is not packing the this sun-resources.xml even i renamed to glassfish-resources.xml but no use. can you suggest anything on this.

Comment: Actually my application is maven based EE application. framework is jsf2.0 IDE netbeans applicationServer Glassfish v3.1

Comment: Maven should automatically package this inside the ear file.  The file should be located in the ear project's resources/META-INF folder.  It sounds like you may not have it in the correct location or you've got some options in your ear pom.xml that are incorrect.

Comment: Additionally, in your persistence.xml, use the correct JNDI name.  For the error given above, the correct name would be `java:app/jdbc/demo7-datasource`.  Note the 'java:app/' prefix for application-scoped resources.

Answer (score 1):

- Start server.
- Go to localhost:4848.
- Configure your jdbc-pool and dont forget to put postgres.jdbc to your `glassfish/glassfish/domain/your_domain/lib/ext`